# How to import my own queue in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am translating a Java program(Queue.java) into a python one(**queue.py**). queue.py failed to be imported in test code in python 3 because it is in conflict with the built-in `queue` module. So built-in `queue` was imported instead.

I knew if I should change my queue.py to any other name, it would work. However, for clarity, I would like to show my audience that Queue.java -> queue.py. So I wondered if there is way to keep the name in python 3.

Here is the [git repo](https://github.com/chfw/alg4_robert_kevin_in_py) where queue.py becomes a problem in python 3. Here is the [travis test](https://travis-ci.org/chfw/alg4_robert_kevin_in_py/jobs/253690871) where it fails. queue.py and test_all.py are in the same directory. Here is how I debugged it:

```
$ nosetests test_all.py:test_queue --pdb
> /Users/jaska/example_code_in_python/test_all.py(83)_verify_module()
-> assert len(params) > 0
(Pdb) print(params)
[]
(Pdb) print(module.__doc__)
A multi-producer, multi-consumer queue.
(Pdb) dir(module)
['Empty', 'Full', 'LifoQueue', 'PriorityQueue', 'Queue', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'deque', 'heappop', 'heappush', 'threading', 'time']
```

Comment: If `queue.py` is in the current directory, `import queue` should use it instead of the built-in `queue` module.  What makes you think that's not what's happening?

Comment: Have you considered putting it in a package?

Comment: I have shared more details about queue.py.

Comment: @jwodder, I did dir(module), which prints many attributes that I do not expect and module.__doc__ string is not the one that I gave.

Comment: if query.py is not in your current directory, use `sys.path.insert(0, <directory_with_query.py>)` before your import

Comment: @TallChuck, I have shared my debug info

Comment: I resorted to change the name in the end. https://github.com/chfw/alg4_robert_kevin_in_py/commit/3c21bc39b298ee273249f6107d80d148e54ab14a